# Assigning dynamic values to an array

Tags: c++

I am making a game kind of like peggle which asks the user how big of a peggle board they want(all triangle),  why many balls they'd like to toss(pings). and the chance to go right o left. I figure im really close i just started getting this error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00DB6253 in lab6.exe: 0xC0000005:
>     Access violation reading location 0xFDFDFDFD.

during runtime on the `counts[init1][init2] = counts[init1][init2] + 1;` line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include "time.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int bins = 0;
    int pings = 0;
    int init1 = 0;
    int init2 = 0;
    int percent;
    cout << "How big would you like the triangle?" << endl;
    cin >> bins;
    cout << "How many pings?" << endl;
    cin >> pings;
    cout << "percent to go right?" << endl;
    cin >> percent;

    int **counts = new int*[bins];
    for (int i = 0; i < bins; i++)
    {
        counts[i] = new int[i + 1];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < bins; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k <= j; k++)
        {
            counts[j][k] = 0;
            //cout << counts[j][k] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pings; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < bins - 1; j++)
        {
            int random = rand() % 101;
            if (random <= percent)
            {
                counts[init1][init2] = counts[init1][init2] + 1;
                init1++;
                init2++;
            }
            else
            {
                init1++;
                if (init2 != 0)
                {
                    init2--;
                }
                counts[init1][init2] = counts[init1][init2] + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < bins; i++)
    {
        delete[] counts[i];
    }
    delete[] counts;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try the simplest of inputs, say, `bins` equal to 1?  You should see that there is a problem right away.

Comment: `init1` and `init2` eventually go out of bounds of your array dimensions, you will need to rethink  your logic

Comment: `int **counts = new int*[bins];` - That's just terrible, terrible C++. **Use `std::vector`.**

Answer (score 0):

In this place:

```
init1++;
if (init2 != 0)
```

you don't check if `init1 < bins` after incrementing it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are doing, but clearly you are not resetting init1 and 2 after inner for loop.

As init1++ is executed pings * (bins - 1) times, it exceeds allocated array size of counts.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got the problem fixed:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pings; i++)
{
    int init1 = 0;
    int init2 = 0;
```

`init1` ranged from 0 to `bins` in the first iteration of the i-loop...but since it wasn't reset, it started next time not at 0 but at `bins`, which is too big.

I'm assuming `init2` also needed resetting to 0, but since I'm not sure what your program's meant to do, I can't swear to it.  If not, you can reset it to whatever's appropriate.